# Nine is the American limit

Tags: riddle

I liked the structure from A.D.'s yet to be answered riddle of similar name and composed something similar.

> First's cost is twice itself
>
> Second's of its name
>
> Third's tiniest of all
>
> Fourth's fourth
>
> Fifth's whole
>
> What is sixth?

**HINT**

> Skip the half

Comment: Shouldn't fifth be half?

Comment: @mmking Nine is the American limit. Why does everyone keep stopping at 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nine are

> Commonly used forms of currency in the US
>  Coins: penny (1 cent), nickel (5 cents), dime (10 cents), quarter (25 cents)
>  Bills: 1 dollar, 5 dollar, 10 dollar, 20 dollar, 100 dollar

First's cost is twice itself

> The metal used in a penny costs roughly twice as much as the face value.

Second's of its name

> A nickel is made of 25% nickel

Third's tiniest of all

> A dime is the smallest coin

Fourth's fourth

> The quarter is a fourth of a dollar

Fifth's whole

> The one dollar bill is a **whole** dollar

What is sixth?

> The five dollar bill

Comment: You got it! I definitely need to work on my riddle-making... or stick my head in the dirt and hide for the rest of my days here.

Comment: @itriedacrab I disagree - I think the riddle was very good with just one or two giveaways that made it too easy! The word 'cost' was a big one, as well as the 'tiniest of all' phrase. If you replaced those with "First is first twice" and "Third's a baby" or something like that, you'd have a really fun puzzle. :) Keep it up!

Comment: @EngineerToast There should only be nine. And if you're going to be picky about it, you should have added the 2 dollar bill too.

Comment: @mmking I'm not sure if you wish to reference the hint, but I think it is referring to skipping the half dollar coin (50 cent coin or half dollar)

Comment: @MarkN I mean in the title, it said nine is the limit. If it hadn't said that, I would have added the 50c coin, the 1 dollar coin, the 2 dollar bill, and the 50 dollar bill. And the 50 dollar bill isn't exactly commonly used. I've never seen an actual one in my life, despite living in the US.

Comment: @mmking The real problem is that 9 isn't the limit. The values are 1c, 5c, 10c, 25c, 50c, 100c (coin), \$1 (bill), \$2, \$5, \$10, \$20, \$50, \$100, and, if you care to get historical, \$500, \$1000, \$5000, \$10000, \$100000. I used a $50 yesterday to buy dinner.

Comment: @EngineerToast Yes I know that. It's just that the question wasn't very well defined. I'm sorry if I came across as rude in my previous comment.

Comment: @mmking I understand and agree. I can't find a good, solid grouping of 9.

Comment: @EngineerToast Sorry about how lax I was in making this. You're saying I should have the title changed to something along the lines of 'Ten is the limit', because of the $50 note, correct?

Comment: @EngineerToast Or that there aren't enough restrictions in the riddle to narrow it down to nine?

Comment: @itriedacrab I think the riddle is OK but the title is misleading

Answer (score 5):

This is about

> US coins.

There are 6 kinds

> currently in circulation: the 1-cent, 5-cent, 10-cent, 25-cent, 50-cent, and 1-dollar coins.

*First's cost is twice itself*

> A 1-cent coin costs roughly 2 cents to produce (thanks @PlayerOne)

*Second's of its name*

> A 5-cent coin is called a nickel and is made partly of nickel.

*Third's tiniest of all*

> The 10-cent coin is the smallest of all.

*Fourth's fourth*

> The 25-cent coin is called a quarter, and a quarter is a fourth or $\frac{1}{4}$.

*Fifth's whole*

> Given the hint "skip the half", I think we're supposed to forget the 50-cent coin, so this is a *whole* dollar.

*What is sixth?*

> A 2-dollar coin?

Comment: If I'm right, the riddle is too easy. I've never been to the US, and got this within 3 minutes!

Comment: I intended it to be simple, but it was too easy ... and you're too sharp! Thanks for highlighting my puzzle-making ineptitude!

Comment: @itriedacrab Sorry, didn't mean to be rude! Here's some more constructive criticism: I think it was the "American" in the title, along with "cost" in the first line immediately making me think of money, that made it too easy. Do keep on posting riddles :-)

Comment: If we're talking about Canadian coins rather than US coins, then the Canadian $1 coin is fifth (as it's a *whole* dollar) and the $2 coin is sixth.

Comment: "Fourth's fourth" 25 cents is quarter of a dollar ie a fourth (and Americans usually call it a quarter, the dime is 10c I think), and 1 cent costs ~2 cents to produce http://blogs.wsj.com/economics/2014/12/15/just-how-much-does-it-cost-to-make-a-penny/

Comment: Thanks PlayerOne; I've incorporated your info. @itriedacrab Is it Canadian as JoeZ says, or US coins? If US, what's the explanation for fifth?

Comment: @randal'thor it's US currency that's in common circulation. Your current answer for sixth isn't the intended answer.

Comment: Ignore the half... I'm kicking myself right now.

Comment: It's not the one dollar coin

Comment: @itriedacrab OK, think I got it now.

Comment: @randal'thor There isn't a 2 dollar coin. The next in the list would be a $2.50 Quarter Eagle coin, but it's no longer in circulation.

Comment: @randal'thor the 50c and the $1 aren't well used. They're rarely found outside of hobbyists' coin collections, if at all. Thus, the riddle is broken as it requires knowledge of what is being commonly used in America.